# What is the NDB equivalent of db._initialize_properties -Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to migrate a project from DB to NDB and found `db._initialize_properties`.

I searched a lot but couldn't find anything related to `_initialize_properties`. Not even in appengine documentation.

Also `_initialize_properties` is not a custom defined function in project.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Code :

`db._initialize_properties(
        model_class, model_class.__name__, model_class.__bases__,
        model_class.__dict__)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's actually no NDB equivalent for that. `_initialize_properties` is actually a internal function of Appengine DB and can be found at `google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py`

If you want to use `_initialize_properties` with NDB, you need to create a custom function in your project with that name and paste the function definition of `_initialize_properties` with modifications that would comply with NDB.